# Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK & Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1

Tags: azure, service, appfabric, servicebus

I'm trying to setup a on-premises environment to run my services on Azure and on an on-premises cluster. I installed on my local Windows Developer machine  ([Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/). Now I want to add the Service Bus environment and I tried to install [Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441412.aspx) - no success.

The Web Platform Installer tries to install Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM first and fails because a higher version of it is already installed.

Here are the individual steps:

- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 with Update (64bit)

Installed:

1. NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
2. Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
3. Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Core SDK 2.1.150 (with Web Platform Installer
   5.0)

**Installing Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 fails**

Dialog:

[image]

This are the webpi1 and windowsfabric log files

**webpi1 log:**

```
: Content-disposition header: attachment
: Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is '0'
: Install return code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is Success
: Product Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) done install completed
: Increasing current install to 2
: Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '14696448'
: Number of bytes after possible decompression: '14696448'
: Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE3CA.tmp' to: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi
: Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi', commandline: 'STARTUPTYPE=disabled IACCEPTEULA=yes PRINCIPALUSER=achibus PRINCIPALDOMAIN=WIN-UVK4P34GL4F ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
: Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/3/3/B33EC622-B250-49A1-A314-97CCB0DEFFC0/WindowsFabricCU1.1.0.976.0.msp' to: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA24.tmp
: MSI install return value for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM' is '1603'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM' is Failure (A higher version of Windows Fabric is already installed.)
: Product Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM done install completed
: Increasing current install to 3
: Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM installation log: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2016-07-08T17.00.19\WindowsFabric.txt
: Content-disposition header: attachment
: Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '10915840'
: Number of bytes after possible decompression: '10915840'
: Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEA24.tmp' to: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric\F7A92FE4B397E73B3B38F3C7717754BF8FC742E3\WindowsFabricCU1.1.0.976.0.msp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1'. Skipping install
: Product Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1'. Skipping download.
: Product Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 5
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798)'. Skipping download.
: Product Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798) had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 6
: Product: VC11Redist_x64, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:01.4774594
: Product: WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:00.1406240
: Product: WindowsFabric, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
: Product: ServiceBus_1_1, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
: Product: ServiceBus_1_1_NETFramework46_Update, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
```

**windowsfabric log:**

```
=== Verbose logging started: 7/8/2016  17:00:22  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPlatformInstaller.exe ===
: Resetting cached policy values
: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
: ******* RunEngine:
       *** Product: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi
       *** Action: 
       *** CommandLine: ***
: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
: Grabbed execution mutex.
: Cloaking enabled.
: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi
: Grabbed execution mutex.
: Resetting cached policy values
: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
: *** RunEngine:
       *** Product: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi
       *** Action: 
       *** CommandLine: ***
: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
: File will have security applied from OpCode.
: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi' against software restriction policy
: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi has a digital signature
: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
: End dialog not enabled
: Original package ==> C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi
: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4234db.msi
: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3}'.
: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 1
: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3}'.
: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
: Transforms are not secure.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2016-07-08T17.00.19\WindowsFabric.txt'.
: Command Line: STARTUPTYPE=disabled IACCEPTEULA=yes PRINCIPALUSER=achibus PRINCIPALDOMAIN=WIN-UVK4P34GL4F ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Packages CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 CLIENTPROCESSID=300 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{ADC98AA8-F7D9-43A3-B078-7668068D23AC}'.
: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3}'
: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3}'
: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
: Product {DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3} is not managed.
: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
: Adding new sources is allowed.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
: Package name extracted from package path: 'WindowsFabric.msi'
: Package to be registered: 'WindowsFabric.msi'
: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
: Running product '{DC35903C-6D48-40A1-BBDD-307E27E691A3}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying STARTUPTYPE property. Its current value is 'auto'. Its new value: 'disabled'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying IACCEPTEULA property. Its current value is 'no'. Its new value: 'yes'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying PRINCIPALUSER property. Its current value is 'NetworkService'. Its new value: 'achibus'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying PRINCIPALDOMAIN property. Its current value is 'NT AUTHORITY'. Its new value: 'WIN-UVK4P34GL4F'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Packages'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI property. Its value is '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '300'.
: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is '6e62cbc4ff4585449d12847c91bf6e2b'.
: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '300'.
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\Favorites
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\Documents
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\Pictures
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\achibus\Desktop
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts
: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Windows User'.
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Installer\4234db.msi'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Users\achibus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\F3D30BA00BE17AF30A841932EEBCB06EB0123955\WindowsFabric.msi'.
: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
=== Logging started: 7/8/2016  17:00:23 ===
: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '603'. Its new value: '601'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '603'. Its new value: '601'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '601'. Its new value: '600'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '601'. Its new value: '600'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '600'. Its new value: '502'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '600'. Its new value: '502'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '502'. Its new value: '501'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '502'. Its new value: '501'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '501'. Its new value: '500'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '501'. Its new value: '500'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '500'. Its new value: '400'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '500'. Its new value: '400'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '14'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '14'. Its new value: '13'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '13'. Its new value: '12'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '12'. Its new value: '11'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '11'. Its new value: '10'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '10'. Its new value: '9'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '9'. Its new value: '8'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '8'. Its new value: '7'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '7'. Its new value: '6'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '6'. Its new value: '5'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '5'. Its new value: '4'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '4'. Its new value: '3'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '3'. Its new value: '2'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ServicePackLevel property. Its current value is '1'. Its new value: '0'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT property. Its current value is '400'. Its new value: '603'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VersionNT64 property. Its current value is '400'. Its new value: '603'.
: Doing action: INSTALL
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 17:00:23: INSTALL.
: Running ExecuteSequence
: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 17:00:23: FindRelatedProducts.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{3C2E3718-7405-4703-A9DF-60BCD02C243D}'.
: Doing action: AppSearch
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:23: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 17:00:23: AppSearch.
: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 3: 2 
: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NETFRAMEWORK40FULL property. Its value is '#1'.
: Doing action: WixQueryOsWellKnownSID
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:23: AppSearch. Return value 1.
: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIEA88.tmp, Entrypoint: WixQueryOsWellKnownSID
: Generating random cookie.
: Created Custom Action Server with PID 2544 (0x9F0).
: Running as a service.
: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM property. Its value is 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSERVICE property. Its value is 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_NETWORKSERVICE property. Its value is 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS property. Its value is 'BUILTIN\Administrators'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS property. Its value is 'BUILTIN\Users'.
: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_ACCOUNT_GUESTS property. Its value is 'BUILTIN\Guests'.
Action start 17:00:23: WixQueryOsWellKnownSID.
: Doing action: LaunchConditions
: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:23: WixQueryOsWellKnownSID. Return value 1.
Action start 17:00:23: LaunchConditions.
: Product: Windows Fabric -- A higher version of Windows Fabric is already installed.

Action ended 17:00:23: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 17:00:23: INSTALL. Return value 3.
: Note: 1: 1708 
: Product: Windows Fabric -- Installation failed.

: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Windows Fabric. Product Version: 1.0.960.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 7/8/2016  17:00:23 ===
: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
: Custom     Action Manager thread ending.
: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/8/2016  17:00:23 ===
```

Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: you don't need WAP ServiceBus, you need Service Bus for Windows Server. WAP SB 1.1 is the integraion component for wap and needs to be installed in a WAP environment. [![service bus vs WAP SB][1]][1] see this documentation for reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441394.aspx 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/08Sew.png

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm still not sure. Your picture shows Service Bus 1.0, but the documentation (that I followed) is describing Service Bus 1.1. The only 1.1 version that is available in the Web Platform Installer is WAP Service Bus 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoting the ms support answer:

“You cannot install Service Fabric and Service Bus on Premise v1.1 on the same machine. As the error suggest (Windows Fabric == Service Fabric this was the pre-release name) and SB1.1 uses an older version. For development purpose you have to develop these on different machines and the same in production.  i.e. Side-by-side is not possible in any configuration. “